# Adding 100 users in powershell script not working

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to add 100 user accounts with PowerShell in my domain system in Windows. I get an error message called "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" when running the script for import.

Error Message:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\user-import.ps1:37 char:9
+         $brukernavn = ($fornavn.Substring(0,3) + $etternavn.Substring ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull*
```

The PowerShell Script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$csvpath = $PSScriptRoot + "\produksjonsbrukereImport.csv"

if (Test-Path $csvpath) {
    #$csvpath = "C:\script\produksjonsbrukereImport.csv"
    $csv = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path $csvpath -Encoding UTF7
    $OUBasePath =  ",OU=Produksjon,OU=OpMeis,DC=OpMeis,DC=local"
    $logpath = "$PSScriptRoot\import-brukere-loggfil.txt"
}

foreach ($line in $csv) {
    $fornavn = $line.fornavn
    $etternavn = $line.etternavn
    $navn = ($fornavn + " " + $etternavn)
    $beskrivelse = $line.beskrivelse

    $passord = $line.Passord
    $avdeling = $line.avdeling

    $brukernavn = ($fornavn.Substring(0,3) + $etternavn.Substring(0,3)).ToLower()
    $brukernavn = $brukernavn -replace "æ", "a"
    $brukernavn = $brukernavn -replace "å", "a"
    $brukernavn = $brukernavn -replace "ø", "o"

    $principal = $brukernavn + "@OpMeis.local"
    $profPath = ($profBasePath + $brukernavn)
    $profPathTrue = $profPath + ".V2"

    $OU = ("OU=" + $avdeling + $OUBasePath)
}
```

Comment: Do you have any blank lines in your csv?

Comment: No blank lines, I filled in every details in the csv file.

Comment: What is the value of `$navn` when the error occurs?

Comment: Maybe try without the substing-part and see what that gets you.

Comment: You may have an undeclared (null) variable. Does $profBasePath have a value?

Comment: Recheck your spelling in the header in the csv file.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Without the subtstring part script is running, but i dont see the new users being add in AD. When i run the script it says completed without creating the accounts. What could be the reason for not adding the accounts?

Comment: New-ADUser -SamAccountName